# Sprite Kit label in the corner

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

What is the best way to add a label at the right or left top corner of the scene? It should be cross-device.

```
let height = self.frame.size.height
let width = self.frame.size.width    
label.fontSize = 50
label.verticalAlignmentMode = .Top
label.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
label.position = CGPoint(x:2, y:height-2)
```

But it would not be in the corner. What is wrong?

Comment: The code you have looks correct, and should put the label in the top left corner with a 2 point buffer in each axis. What is the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: The label is upper than screen. I can subtract 50 or more to see it. If I subtract 2 then it is hidden.

Comment: Then the frame of self is larger than your screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sprite Kit, the default origin of the scene's coordinates is in the bottom left corner of the screen. So, if you want the label in a top corner, you should keep using the screen's height for your label's position, but also use either 0 or the screen's width for the x position. Coupling this with a horizontal alignment mode of left or right depending on the side, and your label will be in the correct position.

For a label in the top left corner:

```
label.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
label.position = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:self.size.height)
```

Or for the top right:

```
label.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Right
label.position = CGPoint(x:self.size.width, y:self.size.height)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can not see the label with such code. May be it is the bug? Is there another version of the Sprite Kit?

Comment: I use iPhone 5s simulator. height-100 will be ok on it. But on iPad Air it will be a big padding from the top.

Comment: @SDmitry Do you have a GameScene".sks" file? If so, make sure it has the proper dimensions, and that your scene's content scale mode is set to a mode that doesn't allow the scene to extend off screen.